# I installed OpenBoard but there's no way to open it

Tags: software-installation, shortcuts

I installed OpenBoard from the software center, it installed, but it's not in my menu so I can't run it.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a broken snap that appears in software centre. There seems to be someone building packages for the Ubuntu based MAX OS: https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/issues/138#issuecomment-406240747